# Conditionally count items in list

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I have prepared the following code:

```
data = []
for i in range(4, 8):
    for value in round(df["month"] / 12, 1) #converting months to years
        if value > i:
        data.append(value)
```

What I am wanting to do is count the number of values stored in this list `data` which are greater than `i` and then store this information in a separate list so I can create a data frame.

I would get something like this:

| Description | Count |
| --- | --- |
| > 4 years | 56 |
| > 5 years | 456 |

I have tried with a `lambda` function but this does not seem to work:

```
data = []
for i in range(4, 8):
    for value in round(df["month"] / 12, 1)
        if value > i:
        data.append(value)
        counts = sum(map(lambda x: if x > i, data)))
```

What can I add to my existing code to get what I want?

Comment: What are you using `range(4,8)` for?

Comment: @RodrigoGuzman its to get the numbers I want to compare the sum of the count. values to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just

```py
over4=(round(df.month/12)>=4).sum()
```

Note: one good rule of thumb to keep in mind *"If I am iterating over pandas rows, I am very probably doing something wrong"*

To create your dataframe

```py
overs=pd.DataFrame([[f"≥{i}",(round(df.month/12)>=i).sum()] for i in range(4,8)], columns=["Description", "count"])
```

Comment: The data frame you have created, is this what's called a list comprehension? also,  what does the **f** do in the part of the code `f"≥{i}",

Comment: Not the dataframe itself, but the list of list from which it is built, that is ``[[f"≥{i}",(round(df.month/12)>=i).sum()] for i in range(4,8)]``, yes, that is list comprehension. And `f"..."` is the notation of f-string. A way to create strings containing values. `f"sin({math.pi})={sin(math.pi)}"` for example is the string `"sin(3.1415926535)=0"`. In other words, each expression between `{...}` inside the string is replaced by its evaluation (unless curly braces are doubled. `f"{{i}}"` is just the literal string `"{i}"`

Comment: So, altogether, given a variable `i`, let say `i=5`, `f"≥{i}"` is the string `"≥5"`. and `(round(df.month/12)>=i).sum()` is the number of row in `df` whose field `.month` is such as `round(df.month/12)` is greater or equal than 5. So `[f"≥{i}",(round(df.month/12)>=i).sum()]` is a list like `["≥5", 165]` (assuming there are 165 rows whose `df.month/12` rounded is ≥5). So `[[f"≥{i}",(round(df.month/12)>=i).sum()] for i in range(4,8)]` is the list of all those pairs, for i from 4 to 7. So something like `[["≥4", 180], ["≥5", 165], ["≥6", 120], ["≥7", 88]]`

Comment: A simpler example combining both list comprehension and f-string, could be `[ f"{x}^2 = {x**2}" for x in range(5) ]` which is the list of 5 strings `['0^2 = 0', '1^2 = 1', '2^2 = 4', '3^2 = 9', '4^2 = 16']`

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation @chrslg

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this line of code. It's not clear if this is the output you want, since we can't look at the data.

```
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(round(df["month"] / 12, 1).value_counts(dropna=True))
```

Or you can alternatively use this to get the table you mention as a dataframe

```
df['foo'] = round(df["month"] / 12, 1)
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Description','Count'])
for i in range(4,8):
    dataFrame.loc[4-i] = [">"+str(i)+" years", (df[df['foo'] > i].foo.count())]
```